# BIOS update fails on Asus motherboard

Tags: motherboard, bios, updates

Why does the A.E.B. fail on a BIOS update from from 0805 to 3703 with this error message?

> image integrity check failed

OS: Windows 7 64-bit
CPU: Intel i5
Mainboard: [Asus P8H67-M EVO](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H67M_EVO/HelpDesk_BIOS/)

Comment: Download the bios image again.

Comment: If downloading the firmware file does not solve the problem, try an incremental upgrade, starting with the first version after 0805 and repeating the process until you install 3703 sucessfully.

Comment: @Armando When following Ramhound's advice, skip the beta versions of the firmware, such as 1850.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in Comments above, you should download the image again from the official server, ensuring that it is standard release, not Early Access or Beta.  Run the upgrade again with the new image.  Discard the problem image.

"Integrity Check" means that they've run a checksum or some other method of confirming that the file is exactly the same as when it left ASUS, and it failed.  It's usually just a flipped bit from a temporary file copy issue.  However, it could mean that someone swapped in malware instead of the valid image.  Either way, just download it again.

ASUS Support is a good resource for precise answers to other BIOS install errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but from my own searches the "image integrity check failed" is a common issue for this motherboard (and a few others of the ASUS P8 series).

A few esoteric "solutions" can be found online, but none of the ones I tried (e.g. using a USB2 port on the board and not on the box, disabling USB3 in the BIOS, etc.) worked, and after trying a couple of times to update the BIOS from the EZ Flash 2 Utility with each available version on ASUS’ website I eventually gave up.

Maybe the tool itself is corrupted, who knows ?  In this case people running Windows might have more chances using the Windows ASUS BIOS update tool.